# Chaining multiple responses to send data and then redirect url

Tags: express, promise, sequelize.js

I am new to javascript and want to know if my code is acceptable: I am using to express to respond to a PUT request. My objective is to send the updated Sequelize model back as a response, and then redirect the user back to the local `/`.

Is chaining the two `.then()` methods with the separate return statements allowed?

The code I am showing is inside a callback function inside my `controller.js`.

```
if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
     return res.status(404).json({ errors: errors.array() });
} else {
    Modules.find({
        where: { id: req.params.id }
    })
    .then(Modules => {
        return Modules.updateAttributes({
        type: req.body.type,
        course: req.body.course,
        start: req.body.start,
        end: req.body.end,
        instructor: req.body.instructor 
          })
     })
     .then(updatedModule => {
          return res.status(204).json(updatedModule); 
     })
     .then(() => {
          return res.redirect(301, "/");
     })
     .catch(() => {
          return res.status(500).json({ errors: errors.array() });      
     });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to send some response back to the user and then want to redirect it back to the baseUrl. 
But sorry to say it is not possible because when you send res to the client back the headers are also sent with that, and after when you use `res.redirect` it will give you an error.

What you can do here is directly redirect a user with `200 status code` like this

```
res.status(200)
res.redirect('/')
```

OR

```
res.redirect(200, '/')
```

and if you are using XHR/AJAX to send request you can write redirection code based on the status code there directly.